# Dialogflow - Retrieve data between timperiod from a Googlesheet

Tags: python, date, google-sheets, dialogflow-es

I use an API named Sheetsu to retrieve data from a Googlesheet.

Here is an example of sheetsu in python to retreive data depending the parameter date:

```
data = client.search(sheet="Session", date=03-06-2018)
```

So this code allow me to retrieve every rows from my sheet call session where colomn date equal 03-06-2018.

What i don't manage to do is to retrieve, with a time value like 16:30:00, every row where the value 16:30:00 is between 2 datetime.

So i would like to know if it is possible to retrieve the data with sheetsu or i should use an another API or if i could use a librairies like datetime to pick the data from sheetsu.

Answer (score 1):

Google Sheets API is available and there's a [Dialogflow-Google Sheets sample](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-telephony-nodejs) up on Github I'd recommend taking a look at to get started. You'll need to ensure that your service account client_email has permission to access that specific spreadsheetId of interest. This sample goes into the necessary auth steps but take a look at the [Sheets documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/reading) as well.